# How can I make parameters that depend on a quarto document's output format?

Tags: r, quarto

For a quarto document with multiple supported output formats, how can I make quarto parameters that are conditional on the active format?

e.g. Suppose I wanted to have one plot background color for HTML output, and a different color for powerpoint? Other applications could be changing character sizes, line weights, etc.

My first thought was ty try placing the `params` YAML block within each format specifier, but that doesn't work.

the following `params.qmd` document fails rendering with an error "object 'params' not found"

````
---
title: "format-driven parameters"
format: 
  html:
    params: 
      plot_bg: "mistyrose"
  pptx:
    params:
      plot_bg: "lightblue"
---


```{r}
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = params$plot_bg, linetype = "blank"))
```
````

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75571053/how-to-detect-the-format-of-output-in-a-currently-executing-knitr

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75105006/10858321) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of a workaround, as it doesn't directly use the YAML parameters for configuration, but achieves the same result in this simple case:

````
---
title: "format-driven parameters"
format: 
  html: default
  pptx: default
---


```{r}
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(ggplot2)

output_format <- knitr::pandoc_to()

if(is.null(output_format)){ #NULL e.g. when running interactively in IDE
  extra_theme <- theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill = "white", linetype = "blank"))
}else if(output_format=="html"){
  extra_theme <- theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill = "mistyrose", linetype = "blank"))
} else if(output_format=="pptx"){
  extra_theme <- theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill = "lightblue", linetype = "blank"))
} else {
  extra_theme <- theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill = "white", linetype = "blank"))
}


ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  extra_theme
```
````

approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75105006/10858321)